# $f \otimes\mathrm{id} : M \otimes A/I \rightarrow N \otimes A/I$ is injective for every ideal $I$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Suppose $f:M\rightarrow N$ is a morphism of $A$-modules. If $f \otimes\mathrm{id} : M \otimes A/I \rightarrow N \otimes A/I$ is injective for every ideal $I$, does this imply $f \otimes\mathrm{id} : M \otimes T \rightarrow N \otimes T$ is injective for every $A$-module $T$?

I think this may be true just like what we do when checking flatness of $A$-module. But this condition is not equivalent to the condition $\operatorname{coker} f$ is flat (take $M=0, N$ not flat). Also one can reduce to the case $T$ is finitely generated as tensor product and colimit commute with each other.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283055/r-i-otimes-pure-exact-sequence

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f\otimes1:M\otimes A/I\to N\otimes A/I$ is injective for every ideal $I$. Then $f$ is injective and we have the SES
$$0\longrightarrow M\xrightarrow{\ f\ }N\longrightarrow\mathrm{coker}(f)=:K\longrightarrow0\ .$$
Tensoring by an $A$-module $T$, we get the LES
$$\cdots\longrightarrow\mathrm{Tor}_1^A(K,T)\longrightarrow M\otimes T\xrightarrow{f\otimes1}N\otimes T\longrightarrow K\otimes T\longrightarrow0\ .$$
Therefore, the maps $f\otimes1$ is injective if, and only if the map
$$\mathrm{Tor}_1^A(K,T)\longrightarrow M\otimes T$$
is trivial. In particular, if $K=\mathrm{coker}(f)$ is flat, then $\mathrm{Tor}_1^A(K,T)=0$ and the statement follows.

I am unsure whether the statement is true if $K$ is not flat.